# clustered (grouped) standard errors Maximum Likelihood R

Tags: r, standard-error, mle, nlm

I'm doing the following maximum likelihood estimation using mle2 function from *[bbmle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bbmle/index.html)* package:

```
llik.probit2<- function(aL,beta, Ks, Kw, Bs, Bw, dta){
  Y <- as.matrix(dta$qualified)
  sce1 <- as.matrix(dta$eds)
  wce1 <- as.matrix(dta$edw)
  sce1_obs <- (as.matrix(dta$eds_obs))
  wce1_obs <- (as.matrix(dta$edw_obs))
  obs <- as.matrix(dta$CombinedObservable1)
  c <- as.matrix(dta$const)
  phi <- pnorm(ifelse(Y == 0, -1, 1) * (-aL*c + beta*obs + (Bs+Bs*Ks-aL)*sce1 -beta*Ks*sce1_obs + (Bw+Bw*Kw-aL)*wce1 - beta*Kw*wce1_obs), log.p = TRUE)
  -sum(phi)
}

starting.pointmle2 <- list(aL=1.4, beta=0.3, Ks=0.5, Kw=0.5, Bs=0.5, Bw=0.5)

result1 <- mle2(llik.probit2, start = starting.pointmle2, data=list(dta=Mydata), skip.hessian=FALSE)
```

I need to estimate clustered standard  errors of this model, clustering on variable *c_id*.  I'm trying to implement the *sandwich* estimator but cannot retrieve 'meat' part from mle2 output. I have also tried with *nlm*, and *optim* (mle2 is basically wrapper for these methods)
Any advice how to do it? In general is there any package which provides functions to calculate clustered standard errors for MLE estimation of a general function?